# RootViewController causing orientation issues in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6

I have an issue with changing my orientation on certain pages in my app. The `shouldAutoRotate`function does not fire on any one page. I have done some digging and hoping someone can tell me if this code is right.

I have a window, a Navigation Controller called homepageController, and a Tab Bar Controller named mainController. The app works as follows. I present the homepageController for the user to log in. Once the correct login key is entered I remove my homepageController view from the window and add the mainController view. Here is the code

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:appDel.homePageController.view.superview cache:NO];

[appDel.homePageController.view removeFromSuperview];

[UIView commitAnimations];

[appDel.window addSubview:appDel.mainController.view];
[appDel.mainController setSelectedIndex:0];
[appDel.window bringSubviewToFront:appDel.mainController.view];
```

I go to my first page on the tab bar and try to rotate it, with a breakpoint on `shouldAutoRotate`, but it never fires.

Again I did some digging and found that my `shouldAutoRotate` method in my .m file for homepageController gets triggered anytime I change orientations. I looked at my xib file and this is what I have.

[image]

I saw that my homepageController is the rootViewController and when switching from tab to tab on the mainController I am using this code.

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

    UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *) viewController;
    [nav popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];

}
```

So seeing that my homepageController is the rootViewController that is why `shouldAutoRotate` always gets called there.

I am wondering if there is a better solution to this. I don't think Im doing this right at all so any guidance would be great.

Thank you

Comment: The rotation scheme was changed completely (and in a largely incompatible fashion) between 5 and 6, and I've not found any coherent discussion of how to handle it in 6, for a range of scenarios.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think `shouldAutoRotate` is not calling because you are using `addSubView:` like

```
[appDel.window addSubView: appDel.mainController]
```

Set your viewcontrollers as rootviewControllers everywhere you have used as addSubview in window.

So use

```
    appDel.window.rootViewController= appDel.mainController;
```

May be now `shouldAutoRotate` will fire event.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: This did not work. This allowed all the screens to be able to turn landscape.